# Highlighting a TreeNode without using foreach, possible with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, treeview

I have a some TreeViews that only contains parent nodes (like a listview). I have a textbox where user can enter a text, then I want to highlight the node in the treeview which has same text as entered by user. At the moment I use this code:

```
strring text = textBox.Text.Trim(); //the text entered by user

foreach(TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
{
    if(node.Text == text) node.BackColor == Color.Green;
}
```

I hate writing foreach for each treeview. Is there a simple way to say for example:

```
if(treeView.Nodes.Contains(text)) //do stuff
```

the `Nodes.Contains()` only accept a TreeNode object. I was wondering if a better code exist out there!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with LINQ like that:

```
treeView.Nodes.FirstOrDefault<TreeNode>(node => node.Text == text);
```

You will get null, if no item was found.

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm how can I translate this to a condition for highlighting the node which returns tru?!

Comment: @Sean87: I would do it this way: `treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes.OfType<TreeNode>().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Text == text);` This will select the first node containing the text or will select no node.

Comment: I tried the code in the answer, `treeView.Nodes` does not have `FirstOrDefault` !?

Comment: @Sean87: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to add `using System.Linq` to the top of your source file.

Comment: Oh thats strange, I added the using statement but VS still does not show .FirstOrDefault method. But I have this method while I work with `List<>` stuff.

Comment: you have to cast to a list before you could apply FirstOrDefault method.

treeView.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().FirstOrDefault(node => node.Text == text);

Comment: @laptop: but you must not if you specify the type with the FirstOrDefault method.

Answer (score 1):

To get all items which contain the text do like that:

```
IEnumerable<TreeNode>  foundItems = 
    from TreeNode node in tree.Nodes 
    where node.Text.Contains(searchString) select node;
```

or to select automatically the first occurence:

```
TreeNode firstNodeWithText = (from TreeNode node in tree.Nodes 
  where node.Text.Contains(searchString) select node).FirstOrDefault<TreeNode>();
tree.SelectedNode = firstNodeWithText;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
string text = textBox.Text.Trim(); //the text entered by user
foreach(TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes
                                 .Cast<TreeNode>()
                                 .Where(x=>x.Text == text))
    node.BackColor == Color.Green;
```

but, as you can see, it is not that shorter from your code.

PS I just realized that you wanted a solution without using foreach. You should try Fischermen's approach then.